# Make Jquery EasyUI work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to implement JQuery EasyUI in ASP.NET and there are two things that I want to clarify.

**Is JQuery EasyUI compatible with ASP.NET specially 3.5?**

I tried working on JQuery EasyUI on ASP.NET yesterday and I was really surprised because for the first run it's not showing me the layout that I'm expecting it seems that the style / css file is not present though I added all the necessary plugins or libraries. This is what exactly happened. First I created an aspx page and incorporated one of JQuery EasyUI demo sample and when I run it the output was really unacceptable. But after trying other demo it worked as well as the first demo when I tried it for the second time. Now I created a new ASP.NET project and do the same thing and woh it's not working for all demos! I tried creating a new project to other pc running window 7 and I'm getting the same bad output. (I'm using xp on the other computer)

**Browser Compatibility?**

All the demos are working properly when I downloaded JQuery EasyUI. From my first concern after creating a new asp.net project from my other computer and run with disoriented output I gave up and just close my VS 2008. I tried running the the demos again under SRWare Iron / Chromium browser and for some reason it's not giving me the output that I expected. I Tried Chrome and still the same issue but when I used Firefox it worked! I tried using Chrome again as if it's a joke it worked as well. But it's still not working in my updated SRWare Iron / Chromium browser though I downloaded JQuery EasyUI using it and run almost all the demos using it and work properly BEFORE.

I don't really have any idea what is happening. By the way I used to computers one from my house and the other is from my office.

Please help me with this I really need advice or answers regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no really relation between asp.net and client side libraries.
The library you are mentioning is 100% depends on client side, so I cant see why it should not be able to run under asp.net project.

I suggest that you use chrome browser to debug the problem.
open chrome -> click f12 -> Network -> open your application
Make sure all of the js + css file were loaded correctly, if not, fix the paths in your html and try again.
Another thing is you should search for js error that may prevent the lib to load correctly.
On the right bottom corner you'll see red X sign if an error accrued.

**If you are running in an error, post it here**

Good luck

Comment: I will surely do this. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and I got an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.easyui.min.js:161
(anonymous function)". Just a note, I'm using the same library for other demos with html extensions.

Comment: Thanks I manage to make it work! Thank you for your advice. Without it I will not be able to make use of Chrome's debugger and figure out the problem. Many thanks to you Cheers!